# Porque um script funciona dentro do HTML e não no JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Estou fazendo uso do toggle para alterar um icone e notei que o script que fiz não funcionava de jeito nenhum, joguei ele dentro do html e funcionou tranquilamente, mas quando jogo ele de volta ao arquivo js dele, onde tem várias funções que eu estou usando, ele simplesmente não funciona mais. o script é esse:

```
$("span#orderColumn").click(function(){
    $("span i.i").toggleClass('halflings-triangle-top halflings-triangle-bottom');
});
```

é bem simples mesmo, mas não está funcionando, ja conferi a ordem de carregamento do Jquery, ja verifiquei se o path está correto, não sei mais o que possa ser

Comment: Provavelmente você está referenciado o Jquery depois do seu Arquivo.Js

Comment: Será que a referência do arquivo que você está utilizando não está errado? No console do navegador mostra alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: ja olhei isso, o jquery ta referenciado antes mesmo, e olhei também se o a referencia estaria errada, mas está puxando normal, o inspect mostra certinho sem nenhum erro de requisição

Comment: A importação do script que você criou está na sessão <head> do html?

Comment: não, estou deixando pro final do html antes de fechar o body, assim não concorre com o carregamento do css e do html,

Comment: Como carregas esse ficheiro `.js` externo? fazes isso no final do body?

Comment: Tenta usar um console.log('antes')  e console.log('dentro') do click ;

Comment: fora ele pega, dentro não

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se de colocar o seu arquivo.js após o jquery.

Coloque esse código também dentro de

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

Comment: já coloquei, ele não funcionou,